# $2016^\frac{k}{n}$ is irrational, where $n\geq 2, 1\leq k<n$.

Tags: calculus

How to show that $2016^\frac{k}{n}$ is irrational, where $n\geq 2, 1\leq k<n$?

Clearly, $2016=2^5\cdot 3^2\cdot 7$. If $2016^\frac{k}{n}=p/q$, with $p,q$ being integers, $(p,q)=1$. Then how to derive a contradiction?

Comment: Nth root of 7 is irrational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p^n / q^n = 2016^k$ is an integer, $$q^n \mid p^n \implies q \mid p \implies q \mid (p,q) = 1$$ so we may assume $q=1.$

Then $7^k \cdot (2^53^2)^k = p^n,$ so if $p = 7^a \cdot M$ where $(7,M)=1$ then 
$$7^k \cdot (2^53^2)^k = 7^{an}\cdot M^n \implies k = an \implies n \mid k$$
which is impossible since $1 \leq k < n.$